# Reward distribution Reinforcement Learning

Tags: reward

Problem1: 
We want to go from s to e. In each cell we can move right R or down D. The environment is fully known. The table has (4*5) 20 cells. The challenge is that we do not know what the reward of each cell is, but we will receive an overall reward as we pass and finish a path. 
Example: a solution can be RRDDRDR and the overall reward is 16.

s   3   5   1   5

1   2   4   5   1

7   3   1   2   8

9   2   1   1   e

The target is to find a set of actions from Start to End which maximizes the obtained overall reward. How can we distribute the overall reward among actions?

Problem2:
This problem is the same as Problem1 but the rewards of problem environment is dynamic so that the way we reach a cell will affect the rewards of cells which are ahead.
Example: for two movements of RRD and DRR, both will get us to the same cell but since they have different path, the ahead cells will have different rewards.

s 3 5  1  5

1 2 4  9 -1

7 3 2 -5 18

9 2 9  7  e

(RRD path, selecting this path will result in changes of rewards of ahead cells)

s 3  5  1  5

1 2  4  3  1

7 3 30  7 -8

9 2 40 11  e

(DRR path, selecting this path will result in changes of rewards of ahead cells)

The target is to find a set of actions from Start to End which maximizes the obtained overall reward. How can we distribute the overall reward between actions? (After passing a path from Start to End and the overall reward is obtained)

Answer (score 0):

Can you say more about the research you are doing? (The problem sounds a lot like the sort of thing someone might assign just to get you thinking about temporal credit assignment.)

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: Ah, I agree. I'm new here. Can I change the status of my "answer" then?

Comment: To be more precise, I am working on Genetic Programming and I want to make a well-structured tree via reinforcement learning. Since a tree is comprised of nodes(as state) and inputs(actions) and a fitness of the tree as my overall reward or gain, I want to build such a tree by utilizing the overall reward and distribute it among the actions and states to find the best actions(function or variable or terminal) for each state(node).